# Reset eth0 to move ubuntu server 14.04

Tags: networking, ubuntu-14.04, eth0, reset

New Ubuntu Server 14.04 instance for installation on a dedicated server.
Everything required is setup as a vbox guest then I add the drive to the allocated server. When I was using 12.04, my last step would be to rm -f /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules to reset eth0.

Ubuntu 14.04 does not use 70-persistent-net.rules anymore. Does anyone know how to reset eth0 for auto config on boot using the new network adapter?

[Ubuntu: Network driver reset to eth0?](https://serverfault.com/questions/353839/ubuntu-network-driver-reset-to-eth0)

[HowTo: Fix a missing eth0 adapter after moving Ubuntu Server from one box to another.](http://www.serenux.com/2009/11/howto-fix-a-missing-eth0-adapter-after-moving-ubuntu-server-from-one-box-to-another/)

[Launchpad Bug #1312785: ethernet Interface naming has changed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/serverguide/+bug/1312785)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Starting with v197 systemd/udev will automatically assign predictable, stable network interface names for all local Ethernet, WLAN and WWAN interfaces. This is a departure from the traditional interface naming scheme ("eth0", "eth1", "wlan0", ...), but should fix real problems.

See if [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/628504/487649) helps; [here](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/) and [over there](https://major.io/2015/08/21/understanding-systemds-predictable-network-device-names/) some more background on the topic, if you're interested.

Comment: I edited /etc/network/interfaces to match the current convention for embedded NICs.

eth0 to em1.

Is this an acceptable answer? I will force the use of eth0 in the future due to other servers using dedicated network cards.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/578650/interface-device-name-em1-to-eth0-linux-14-04-lts

Comment: I have fixed the issue with the current server by changing the name but a better solution in the future will be to ensure eth0 is used. I'll mark your answer as the solution. Thanks for the assistance. The links you posted are required reading.